# Disable hot keys for find on desktop so I can use them for guake terminal

Tags: 22.04

So I like using guake terminal on ubuntu. I recently updated to 22.04 and now when I use crtl-t it opens a box for search on desktop. Im in such a habit of using crtl-t to get a fast drop down terminal in guake it's really hard to switch. I did try making a switch to fn-super-t and it works to open guake in every appliction(chrome, krusader, firefox) but doesn't work if I'm on the desktop with not in an application. I'd really like to be able to set my guake back to crtl-t. It's getting really frustrating. I wonder if there is some way to edit in dconf-editor. Any help will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Figured it out.  quake is not that compatible with Wayland.  In Wayland I was able to kind of get working with a keyboard shortcuts to quake -t but it's not as snappy as just using Xorg.

Comment: Great!  It would help those that follow if you answer your own question and maybe show how you switch desktop managers?  (/etc/gdm3/custom.conf maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

Guake has a lot of problems with Wayland as you said it is best to stay on Xorg for now.
For example it will only open the terminal on your primary display, the option for Appear on mouse display is not working yet even after almost a year of the bug being reported.

@Frobozz
The way to change to Xorg is to logout and in the bottom right part of your screen you will find a settings icon which will have the option Ubuntu on Xorg.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).